# Capture screenshot from another ViewController - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently using:

```
        CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
        UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This retrieves a screen shot of the current view once a `UITabBarItem` is selected.  The problem is, this will always capture the `view` of the `current view` the user is active on before switching to the next `view`.

To better understand this.  I have a `UITabBarController` that manages my navigation for my app.  The walk in `View controller` is a table that I want to always capture a picture of when the user selects the `Share` `UITabBarItem` on the navigation.  So I have this linked to a method that checks to see if `Share` has been clicked and creates an image of the current view as shown above.

My roadblock is, `how can I capture an image of that first view(walk in view) every time no matter what view the user is currently on?`

I am handling my capturing functionality within a custom class that initates the `UITabBarController`

Suggestions thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this help you?

```
CGRect rect = [yourTabController.viewControllers[walkInViewIndex].view bounds];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[yourTabController.viewControllers[walkInViewIndex].view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: So what you are saying is get the `tabbarcontrollers viewcontroller` based on index of the `tabbaritems`? Than process it that way?

Comment: Yes if the "index" properly identifies the viewController whose screen shot you wanted to capture.

Comment: Let me check this out!

Comment: Questions, what is my definition of `walkInViewIndex`  That is not suppose to be the index number correct?

Comment: walkInViewIndex I mentioned here is the index of the tab page which holds the view controller whose screen shot you want to capture. Suppose you always wanted to capture screen shot of view controller at tab index 0. then the code will be yourTabController.viewControllers[0].view

Comment: Thats what I thought, the issue though is I am getting a view not found on object of type id when doing that.  I am using `self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0].view bounds`

Comment: Are you adding your controller to UITabBarContoller using the  [_yourTabBarContoller addChildViewController:yourViewController];

Comment: No I have my storyboard assigning my `UITbarBarController` to this custom class and I have my `UITabBar assigned to a IBOutlet`.  Other than that I've simply been using `self.tabBarController`

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
```

This explicitly takes a snapshot of the current view (self.view).  What you'll want to do is more or less the same procedure, but by specifying your walk in view instead:

```
[self.walkingController.view.layer renderInContext:context];
```